# What is Evidence-Based Software Engineering?

Tags: methodology

It looks like some new fancy methodology named EBSE is coming upon us in 2010.

Can someone explain it to me, please?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [official website](http://www.dur.ac.uk/ebse/), "EBSE is concerned with determining what works, when and where, in terms of software engineering practice, tools and standards".

Basically, EBSE is inspired in medical practice and other professions with similar trajectories, and tries to apply their empirical, down-to-earth approach to the often chaotic world of software development.

Comment: This strongly reminds me of the advice given in the book The Mythical Man-Month. :)

Comment: That's an interesting insight.

Answer (score 12):

The EBSE stands for Evidence-based software engineering. The concept tries to bring evidence to decisions made in the software engineering.

The main instrument of EBSE is the systematic literature review (SLR). The concept is derived from medicine and was adapted by Kitchenham in 2004 in the paper [Procedures for perfoming systematic reviews](http://artemisa.unicauca.edu.co/~ecaldon/docs/spi/kitchenham_2004.pdf). The idea behind the SLR is to obtain accurate data by analyzing other primary studies, eliminating possible bias that this studies may suffer.

Since 2004 multiple authors proposed changes to Kitchenham's procedure, but Kitchenham remains as the ultimate authority in SLRs in software engineering.

Some popular SLR papers are [Empirical studies of agile software development: A systematic review](http://alarcos.inf-cr.uclm.es/doc/MetoTecInfInf/Articulos/dyba.pdf) and [Lessons from applying the systematic literature review process
within the software engineering domain](http://alarcos.esi.uclm.es/doc/MetoTecInfInf/Articulos/Breretonetal-JSS2007.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I don't see that evidence based software engineering is any different from empirical or experimental software engineering. (ESE) They all have the intention of replacing opinion with a scientific epistemology for the creation of knowledge about how software is/can be created. The International Conference of Software Engineering (http://www.icse-conferences.org/) always has papers on this topic.

Answer (score -5):

Do you mean [evidence-based scheduling](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2007/10/26.html)?  The basic gist is that estimates for features in development should be based on statistics gathered about how long previously completed features took.

Comment: No. I mean EBSE.  But thank you, the fogbugz is too well known tool to cause any questions.